# How to disable set random order of schedule in TUI-Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, calendar, toast

I am using **toast UI calendar** for making schedule management in the Laravel project.
But I need to disable random order of schedule every day.

This is screenshot
[image: This is before clicking the refresh button]

If I click the refresh button it will change like the below screenshot.
[image: This is after clicking the refresh button]

This is **generateSchedule** function

```
function generateSchedule(viewName, renderStart, renderEnd, check_key) {
  ScheduleList = [];
  realize_schedule.forEach(function(real_item){
    var i = 0, length = 1;
    if (viewName === 'month') {
      length = 1;
    } else if (viewName === 'day') {
      length = 2;
    }
    for (i; i < length; i += 1) {
      var index_calendar = real_item.roomRate_type;
      if(index_calendar > 0){
        index_calendar = index_calendar-1;
      }
      if(check_key === ""){
        generateRandomSchedule(CalendarList[index_calendar], real_item, new Date(real_item.start), new Date(real_item.end));
      }else{
        if(check_key === real_item.roomRate_nameCode){
          generateRandomSchedule(CalendarList[index_calendar], real_item, new Date(real_item.start), new Date(real_item.end));
        }
      }
    }
  })
}
```

This is **generateRandomSchedule** function

```
function generateRandomSchedule(calendar, roomRate, renderStart, renderEnd) {
  var schedule = new ScheduleInfo();

  schedule.id = roomRate.id;
  schedule.calendarId = calendar.id;

  schedule.title = calendar.name;
  schedule.body = roomRate.roomRate_nameCode;
  schedule.isReadOnly = false;
  generateTime(schedule, renderStart, renderEnd);
  schedule.isPrivate = false;
  schedule.location = roomRate.roomRate_value;
  schedule.state =roomRate.status;
  schedule.attendees=[roomRate.night_stayval];
  schedule.recurrenceRule = roomRate.allotmant;

  schedule.color = calendar.color;
  schedule.bgColor = calendar.bgColor;
  schedule.dragBgColor = calendar.dragBgColor;
  schedule.borderColor = calendar.borderColor;

  if (schedule.category === 'milestone') {
    schedule.color = schedule.bgColor;
    schedule.bgColor = 'transparent';
    schedule.dragBgColor = 'transparent';
    schedule.borderColor = 'transparent';
  }

  schedule.raw.memo = chance.sentence();
  schedule.raw.creator.name = chance.name();
  schedule.raw.creator.avatar = chance.avatar();
  schedule.raw.creator.company = chance.company();
  schedule.raw.creator.email = chance.email();
  schedule.raw.creator.phone = chance.phone();
  schedule.raw.creator.bug = "";

  if (chance.bool({ likelihood: 20 })) {
    var travelTime = chance.minute();
    schedule.goingDuration = travelTime;
    schedule.comingDuration = travelTime;
  }

  ScheduleList.push(schedule);
}
```

So I want to disable that random feature for schedule order in the day field.
Please help me if anybody has experience in it.

Comment: Can you share your code please?

Comment: So what code? I use just library 'tui-calendar'

Comment: I think it is impossible to arrange orderly.

Answer (score 1):

Please see this...
[enter link description here](https://ui.toast.com/tui-calendar/)

You can see reference code from that url.
If you want to disable random to set order of schedule, it may changed some code of libarary.

Comment: I saw this page, But I can't find any solution.

Comment: You can find **generateSchedule** function in _schedules.js_.
should change in there.

Comment: Yest. I find that.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is impossible because these schedule are arranged random.
So you should to use **createSchedules** function orderly.

For example, you create schedule with this function one by one.
I think this is only solution for that.

Comment: So it should be parameter one schedule?

Comment: Yes. Schedule array data that has one cell.

Answer (score 0):

You should to change content of **gnerateRandomSchedule**.
I think it is better to upload that function too.

Comment: I edited that. Please check in there. I can't find anything to solve that in that function.

Comment: So what should I change in there?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change child order of **realize_schedule** list.
In **generateSchedule**, this list is explained orderly.

```
realize_schedule.forEach(function(real_item){
  var i = 0, length = 1;
  if (viewName === 'month') {
    length = 1;
  } else if (viewName === 'day') {
    length = 2;
  }
  for (i; i < length; i += 1) {
    var index_calendar = real_item.roomRate_type;
    if(index_calendar > 0){
      index_calendar = index_calendar-1;
    }
    if(check_key === ""){
      generateRandomSchedule(CalendarList[index_calendar], real_item, new Date(real_item.start), new Date(real_item.end));
    }else{
      if(check_key === real_item.roomRate_nameCode){
        generateRandomSchedule(CalendarList[index_calendar], real_item, new Date(real_item.start), new Date(real_item.end));
      }
    }
  }
})
```

So do like that.

Comment: Yes. But This is arranged orderly.

Answer (score 0):

I think about this problem for long times.
But it is impossible to arrange orderly.
Because this use **createSchedules** function to create schedules.
Before calling this function, schedules are arranged orderly.

This is code example.

```
function setSchedules() {
  cal.clear();
  generateSchedule(cal.getViewName(), cal.getDateRangeStart(), cal.getDateRangeEnd(), filter_Code);
  cal.createSchedules(ScheduleList);
  console.log(ScheduleList);
  refreshScheduleVisibility();
}
```

You can see scheduleList with *console.log()*.
Sorry for making code in hand.

If you have any question, let me know.

Comment: I think it is true.

Comment: I will find more solutions for that.